# Relative Path Handling by scandir

Tags: c, relative-path, scandir

Does the function scandir handle relative paths?

In other words, are the following two pieces of code equivalent?

```c
int NUM = scandir("/home/hello/wait/../pqr/../../hello", &LIST, 0, alphasort);
```

```c
int NUM = scandir("/home/hello", &LIST, 0, alphasort);
```

If not, is there some simple buit-in function to convert `/home/hello/wait/../pqr/../../hello` to `/home/hello`?

Comment: You can build the function to canonise the path yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the function scandir handle relative paths?

I believe the answer is yes. From [posix scandir](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alphasort.html) we know only that:

> The scandir() function shall scan the directory dir, [...]

From posix definitions:

> 3.129 Directory
>
> A file that contains directory entries. No two directory entries in the same directory have the same name

The argument to `scandir` is `char *`, so it's a string. And from posix definitions we know that:

> 3.271 Pathname
>
> A string that is used to identify a file. [...]

Another section named `4.13 Pathname Resolution` delves on how pathname is resolved, and tells us that:

> If the pathname does not begin with a <slash>, the predecessor of the first filename of the pathname shall be taken to be either the current working directory of the process [...] (such pathnames are referred to as "relative pathnames").

So because `scandir` takes a pathname to a directory and because of how a pathname is resolved, yes, you can give relative paths to scandir.

---

> In other words

It's not an "other word" - both pathnames you showed are absolute, not relative. Using *dot-dot* in a pathname doesn't make the pathname relative.

> are the following two pieces of code equivalent?

Yes.

---

> is there some simple buit-in function to convert /home/hello/wait/../pqr/../../hello to /home/hello?

There is no ["builtin function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) to canonicalize a pathname in any compiler I am aware of. There exists a completely normal function provided from POSIX for that purpose and is called [realpath()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realpath.html). GNU library may allocated the returned string dynamically and it also has [canonicalize_file_name](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/canonicalize_file_name.3.html).